# Output for below scenario

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, case

Having 2 tables T1 and T2

In T1 table view_report column is there it's empty
In T2 table 6 columns are there and data is exactly shown below

```
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6
1  1  1  0  0  0
0  1  0   1  0  0
1  0  0  0   0   0
```

I want to populate the view_report column by checking all the 5 column data in T2 table
like when Q1 = 1 then A
Q2 = 1 then B and so on

NOTE: for all 6 columns if not equal to 1 then it should be null

but in 1st row if we have Q1, Q2, Q3 values are 1 then my output should be A,B,C

Kindly help me to resolve this question in Oracle SQL

Comment: please study this first [Punctuation - Signs and Symbols](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/write/punctuation1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a list of the columns that have flags:

```
select t.*,
       trim(',' from
            (case q1 when 1 then 'A' || ',' end ||
             case q2 when 1 then 'B' || ',' end ||
             case q3 when 1 then 'C' || ',' end ||
             case q4 when 1 then 'D' || ',' end ||
             case q5 when 1 then 'E' || ',' end ||
             case q6 when 1 then 'F' || ',' end
            )
           ) as view_report
from t;
```